# Card payment error - 508 Mandatory field missing. HPP_BILLING_CITY not present in request. Please contact the merchant

Tags: payment-gateway, card, realex-payments-api, global-payments-api

I am using realex payment 3DS2 on ectdrains.co.uk and after i hit "Pay Now" on the checkout page it return this Error: 508 Mandatory field missing. HPP_BILLING_CITY not present in request. Please contact the merchant.

Any idea what is mean and how to solve this issue?

The billing_city is added to checkout page:

Answer (score 0):

It would be worth checking that the billing_city is mapping to the HPP_BILLING_CITY field when it's submitted.  Looking at your site, if you're using Wordpress / WooCommerce then I'd suggest making sure your plugins are up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Please download and install the latest extension/plugins and that should go away.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).